# Cannot use hasMany relationship on for loop in view (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, has-many

I am trying to code an app which has several "Locations" which users can add as their favorites. I have a model for Locations, a model for Favorites and a database table where I log pairs of user_id and location_id to indicate a user's favorite locations.

In my Location model I have defined the following hasMany relationship:

```
public function favorites(){
  return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

I have also defined the inverse relationship on the Favorite model as follows:

```
public function location(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
}
```

Then in a view I'm trying to get a list of all locations and mark those which the user has marked as favorite. To do this I am looping through all locations, and trying to get a count on how many favorites the location has. It should be either 1 or 0, since the user_id/location_id combination row only exists if the user has the specific location as hi favorite.

Here is the relevant part of the code (I am passing a list of locations to the view):

```
@foreach ($Locations_List as $Location)
      {{ $Location->favorites()->get()->count }}
@endforeach
```

Here is how I'm passing the $Locations_List:

```
  public function Create_SearchResults(){

$Locations_List = Location::select('id', 'Name', 'Category', 'Logo', 'Status', 'Address_Number', 'Address_Street', 'Address_City', 'Updated_At')
  ->where('Status', '>=', 500)
  ->get();

return view('Location_Search/Index', compact('Locations_List'));
```

}

However, when I try the above, I get "Property [count] does not exist on this collection instance.".

I have tried doing something similar to the above in tinker, and it does work. However, I had to resolve the "array" piece of it as follows:

```
$loc = App\Location::find(2);
$loc->favorites()->get()->count();
```

How do I get over the "array" issue on the view? Thanks in advance

Comment: how you get `$Locations_List` variable, show your controller code please. And also , you should not call get() inside loop, use EagerLoading instead

Comment: The most important part of your code is missing from your question so it's really difficult for anyone to help you out here. The error is telling you `$Locations_List` is an array and that it cannot call the function `favourites()` on an array, which is correct. This should immediately trigger your mind with, wait, why is it an array? It's supposed to be a collection of models.

So, as @Zuko said, please share where you are defining `$Locations_List` and we'll more than likely immediately see what's causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't think of the way I'm passing $Locations_List as being the potential issue. I was indeed passing as array and I've edited as shown above. Please see above the edited text for the controller code and updated error I'm getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `{{ $Location->favorites->count() }}` inside the `foreach` loop.

Alternatively, you can eager load the counts in the controller by adding

`->withCount('favorites')` when initializing `$Locations_List`:

```
$Locations_List = Location::select('id', 'Name', 'Category', 'Logo', 'Status', 'Address_Number', 'Address_Street', 'Address_City', 'Updated_At')
  ->withCount('favorites')
  ->where('Status', '>=', 500)
  ->get();
```

In this case, you can simply put `$Location->favorites_count` in the `foreach` loop.